# Looping and bitmaps: How do I dispose of emgu image(Of bgr, byte) when looping?

Tags: image, bitmap, dispose, emgucv

How do you dispose of bitmaps and images when in a for...next loop?

Particularly `image(of bgr, byte)` images.

The "image(of bgr, byte)" images are from the emgu library.

The `Dispose()` command works fine when you dispose of a single bitmap or image.

But when you are looping through multiple images, Outofmemory errors occur.

Even when applying the `using ... end using` commands, memory issues occur.

For example, this will throw memory errors for me:

```
Dim pic As Bitmap = New Bitmap(270, 100)
For i = 0 to 100
    Dim CleanImage As New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(pic)

    'this command comes from the emgu library - tesseract
    OCRz.Recognize(CleanImage)    

    CleanImage.Dispose()

Next
```

As will:

```
Dim pic As Bitmap = New Bitmap(270, 100)
For i = 0 to 100
    Using CleanImage As New Image(Of Bgr, Byte)(pic)  
        OCRz.Recognize(CleanImage)    
    End Using
Next
```

I've tried `GC.Collect()`. This didn't work.

How do I properly rid the program of these annoying bitmaps and images?

I'm desperate for a solution.

The emgu wiki states the following:

> Automatic Garbage Collection The Image class
>   automatically take care of the memory management and garbage
>   collection.
>
> Once the garbage collector decided that there is no more reference to
>   the Image object, it will call the Disposed method,
>   which release the unmanaged IplImage structure.
>
> The time of when garbage collector decides to dispose the image is not
>   guaranteed. When working with large image, it is recommend to call the
>   Dispose() method to explicitly release the object. Alternatively, use
>   the using keyword in C# to limit the scope of the image
>
> ```
> using (Image<Gray, Single> image = new Image<Gray, Single>(1000, 800))
>
>  {  
>
>         ... //do something here in the image 
>
>  } //The image will be disposed here and memory freed
> ```

This is exactly what I am doing.  Yet, I receive this OutOfMemory exception.  What is going on?